# counting from textbox,asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I count characters in a TextBox using ASP.NET(C#)?

Answer (score 8):

This is the property to see how long the text is during a postback:

```
TextBox.Text.Length;
```

TextBox:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx

Text Property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text.aspx

String Length Property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx

```
String str = TextBox.Text;

if(str.Length > 50)
{
   str = str.SubString(0, 50) + "<br/>" + str.SubString(50);
}
```

Comment: How to count charachters in the textbox,and if the nubmers goes over 50 that add <br/>tag in charachters?

Answer (score 0):

How to count charachters in the textbox,and if the nubmers goes over 50 that add 
tag in charachters?

Answer (score -1):

For count characters

```
TextBox.Text.Length;
```

and if you want validate number goes over 50 that add tag in text.

Maybe this in my perception:

```
int countWord = Textbox.Text.Length();

if(countWord > 50){
    string text = Textbox.Text.ToString()+"SomeTag";
}else{
    string text = Textbox.Text.ToString();
}
```